# How do I display different modal/modal content when I clicking on the different Icons (Not Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to get the other icons to work how the "Operations Management" is working. But I want it to say different things.

PLEASE HELP :(

Here is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/RonaLochner/p4kt6oy1/

The Code:

```
<div class='circle-container'>
    <a href='#' class='center'>
        <h4 style="text-align:center;">Microsoft Dynamics 365</h4>
    </a>
    <div id="operations-management">
        <img src='http://www.businesscentral.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Business-Solutions-Icon2.png'>
    </div>

    <div id="reporting">
        <img src='http://www.businesscentral.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Business-Solutions-Icon3.png' id="myBtn">
    </div>
    <div id="supplychain">
        <img src='http://www.businesscentral.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Business-Solutions-Icon4.png' id="myBtn">
    </div>
    <div id="sales">
        <img src='http://www.businesscentral.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Business-Solutions-Icon5.png' id="myBtn">
    </div>
    <div id="financial">
        <img src='http://www.businesscentral.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Business-Solutions-Icon6.png' id="myBtn">
    </div>
    <div id="project">
        <img src='http://www.businesscentral.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Business-Solutions-Icon1.png' id="myBtn">
    </div>
</div>
```

The model:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>OPERATIONS MANAGEMENT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Script

```
<script>

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal')

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("operations-management");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

I have tried to target using different ID's but not sue how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first thing you want to do is add a class to each of the icons/buttons like so;

```
<div class="toggle" id="operations-management">
    <img src='http://www.businesscentral.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Business-Solutions-Icon2.png'>
</div>
```

Then you want to call them using querySelectorAll and convert it to array

```
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btns = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".toggle"));
```

We convert it to array because querySelectorAll returns a node list but we need an array to iterate through all the buttons so thats where the Array. So then we itierate over all of the buttons and add a event listener that points to a new function showModal

```
btns.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", showModal);
});
```

The showModal function will show the modal.

```
function showModal(e) {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

now you have you probably want to have different content in each modal right? I would make the p tag in your modal with an id and then using the (e) variable from the showModal function I would find the id of the button and then have an if statment that would change the modal p tag depending on the id that is passed from e. (if you set console.log(e) just before I set the modal.style.display you will see an object and there you can find the id.

Comment: Oh my Gosh!!  **THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!** Saved my butt! and totally understand this now!

Comment: @RonaLochner youre welcome! dont forget to mark this as answered if it answered you question :-)

Comment: Another option: https://jsfiddle.net/RonaLochner/p4kt6oy1/90/

Here is another solution my friend sent me. Just in case anyone else has this problem :)

Thanks again!